# Ableton Levels changing themselves?

Tags: ableton-live

I am very new to able and I'm using Ableton Live 9 Lite. I have eight tracks and as I'm mixing I notice that some of the levels of my tracks have a little red dot on them (as do my reverb and delay sends). I think this might have something to do with clipping but I'm not sure.

The problem comes in when these levels will randomly turn themselves up. I don't know why they are doing that and how to turn it off?

Has anyone experienced this before? Image of the red dots below:

[Red Dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQBaU.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

This means that you have enabled automation, very likely because you recorded with automation enabled. If you right-click on the control you can choose "Delete Automation" to remove the automation entirely.